# Error building cordova android apk in Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing an android apk with cordova using Visual Studio. I have no problem with debugging in the browser and I hadn't problems to release the apk file some days ago but yesterday I wanted to release the apk again to test some new part of my app but I got this error.
I've already read other related topics but I still can't solve this.
The errors:

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\gradlew.bat cdvBuildRelease -b C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:


1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':processReleaseResources'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

The error list screenshot (the same as above)
[image]

**UPDATE:**

I've run --stacktrace with --debug and here is the error I got in the output:

```
 15:27:43.275 [ERROR][org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator] Failed to notify      
 ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), but primary configuration failure takes precedence.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: buildToolsVersion is not specified.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:606)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:572)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:569)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:568)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:565)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
 15:27:43.290 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Where:
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Script 'C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 117
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
 15:27:43.292 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Unable to determine Android SDK directory.
 15:27:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
 15:27:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
 15:27:43.293 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:157)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:162)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:529)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:90)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
 15:27:43.294 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
 15:27:43.295 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
 15:27:43.296 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to determine Android SDK directory.
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at cordova_5h469rfrikiuvyo00zkjn2dzm.getAndroidSdkDir(C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle:117)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at cordova_5h469rfrikiuvyo00zkjn2dzm.getAvailableBuildTools(C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle:39)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at cordova_5h469rfrikiuvyo00zkjn2dzm.doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools(C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle:48)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at cordova_5h469rfrikiuvyo00zkjn2dzm$_run_closure1$_closure13.doCall(C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle:188)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at cordova_5h469rfrikiuvyo00zkjn2dzm$_run_closure1$_closure13.doCall(C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.methodMissing(DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.java:75)
 15:27:43.297 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at build_dtzhsouusuqggyxz4wzhnqxu9.run(C:\Users\natva\Desktop\Proyecto\aplicacion\Proyecto\Pawpals\Pawpals\platforms\android\build.gradle:103)
 15:27:43.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
 15:27:43.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 50 more
 15:27:43.298 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
 15:27:43.298 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
 15:27:43.298 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
 15:27:43.298 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
 15:27:43.298 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 13.679 secs
```

**SECOND UPDATE:**

config.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="io.cordova.myapp8f2f02" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="es-ES">
    <name>Pawpals</name>
    <description>Un proyecto en blanco que usa Apache Cordova para ayudarle a compilar una aplicación que tiene varias plataformas móviles como destino: Android, iOS y la plataforma universal de Windows.</description>
    <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Pawpals</author>
  <vs:template-name>BlankJS</vs:template-name>
  <vs:toolsetVersion>6.3.1</vs:toolsetVersion>
  <engine name="android" spec="5.2.1" />
  <engine name="ios" spec="4.2.0" />
  <engine name="windows" spec="4.4.2" />
  <content src="index.html" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/pata.png" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" height="44" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" height="71" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
  </platform>
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-geolocation" spec="~1.0.6" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <access origin="pawpals.social" />
  <access origin="https://maps.googleapis.com/*" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~2.0.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="~1.0.2" />
    </widget>
```

Comment: Can you run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. and post here

Comment: I've run that and I've updated the main post with the output errors.

Comment: Have you set ANDROID_HOME  in your environment variables ? and also post yoyr config.xml.

Comment: Yes, I've checked ANDROID_HOME and is there. config.xml added.

Comment: Try android-versionCode="1"  in your widget tag

Comment: Nothing, I have the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203398/discussion-between-swayangjit-and-harukauni).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft pretty much dropped support for Cordova.  The best thing to do is command line builds for android.  make sure you install the latest cli and android platforms